# what to use instead of union to join same results based on two where clauses

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have two queries that work as expected for example

Query 1

```
select Name,ID,Product,Question
from table 1
where Id= 9 and ProductID=30628
```

table output

```
Name               | ID  | Product | QUestion
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12356|Apple    | is it picked up?
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12456|Apple    |Available in store?
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12458|Apple    |confirm order?
```

query 2

```
select Name,ID,Product,Question
    from table 1
    where Id= 9 and TypeID=2
```

table output

```
Name               | ID  | Product | QUestion
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12347|Apple    | Problem at store?
```

as you can see in query 1 i use a ProductID and in query 2 i use a TypeID these two values gives me different out puts

so i used a union to join both as follows

```
select Name,ID,Product,Question
from table 1
where Id= 9 and ProductID=30628
union
select Name,ID,Product,Question
    from table 1
    where Id= 9 and TypeID=2
```

which i get the desired output

```
Name               | ID  | Product | QUestion
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12356|Apple    | is it picked up?
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12456|Apple    |Available in store?
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12458|Apple    |confirm order?
0659e103-b33d-4603 |12347|Apple    | Problem at store?
```

is their a better way to do this because my query will grow and i would not like to repeat the same thing over again. is their a better way to optimize the query?

NOte i can not use ProductID and TypeID on the same line because they do not result in accurate results

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OR` since you are querying the same table.

```
SELECT Name
    ,ID
    ,Product
    ,Question
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (
        Id = 9
        AND ProductID = 30628
        )
    OR (
        Id = 9
        AND TypeID = 2
        )
```

If you have a growing number of OR conditions you could use a temp table/variable and inner join to profit from a set based operation.

The inner join will only return matching rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #SomeTable(Id INT NOT NULL, ProductID INT NULL, TypeID INT NULL)

-- Insert all conditions you want to match.
INSERT INTO #SomeTable(Id, ProductID, TypeId)
VALUES (9, 30628, NULL)
, (9, NULL, 2)

SELECT Name
    ,ID
    ,Product
    ,Question
FROM TABLE1 x
INNER JOIN #SomeTable y ON 
    x.ID = y.ID -- Since ID is Not null in the temp table
    AND (y.ProductID IS NULL OR y.ProductID = x.ProductID)
    AND (y.TypeID IS NULL OR y.TypeID = x.TypeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cas-when clause with a self join.

Case-when something like this:

```sql
SELECT t1_2.Name,
       t1_2.ID,
       t1_2.Product,
       t1_2.Question,
       (CASE WHEN (t1.Id= 9 and t1.ProductID=30628) THEN ID 
             WHEN (t1.Id= 9 and t1.TypeID=2) THEN ID 
        ELSE NULL) AS IDcalc
FROM table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN table_1 t1_2 
     ON t1.ID = t1_2.ID
     WHERE (CASE WHEN (t1.Id= 9 and t1.ProductID=30628) THEN ID 
                 WHEN (t1.Id= 9 and t1.TypeID=2) THEN ID 
            ELSE NULL) IS NOT NULL
```

You can use any table in the join.

In comparison of query performance the `OR` is much better until you have only one table, if you have more tables, then you should use **temp table** or **case-when** in your query.